# VBA IE password Issue

Tags: html, vba

everything works fine on below code except password.
usually, the password goes like *********, but this case just shows:abcd99999
as result, when click, it just shows" please enter your password"
kindly help me, thanks

```
Sub hncb()

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate ("https://ibank.hncb.com.tw/netbank/servlet/TrxDispatcher?trx=com.lb.wibc.trx.Login&state=prompt&Recognition=company")
ShowWindow ie.hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED

Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

ie.Document.forms(0).all("USERID").Value = "abcded"
ie.Document.forms(0).all("NICKNAME").Value = "abcd1234"

ie.Document.forms(0).all("pwdText").Value = "abcd99999"    ---this line got me in trouble

Set obja = ie.Document.getElementById("WannaLogin").getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
obja.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe `ie.Document.forms(0).submit`

Comment: Does VBA has the SendKeys() option? If so, try that...

Comment: In the end, i used sendkeys, it worked.